# reduce number of characters in Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contactbuilder

I´ve created an data extension with a lot of fields (~400). Each field is formatted with a maximum of 4.000 characters.
When calling the table salesforce loads very long and I think it is due to the 4000 characters. In the Contact Builder I can only increase the number of characters, not reduce them.
Do you have any idea to reduce the characters or create a copy of this table as easy as possible without having to create each field manually?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say you have to do it by hand or use APIs (retrieve the old dataextension change all data types and create a new dataextension with it). (when this table would have 1Million rows that would be 1600 or 3200 GB (if my math is correct, which i doubt right now). Do not ever create tables like this...

Comment: To hop on @JohannesSchapdick's comment, I would highly recommend using this as an opportunity to break apart this DE into a group of DEs all connected with a unique ID, This will create a much faster process and will likely allow you to sectionalize your data so that it does not have to be a bulk update/export each time.

Answer (score 0):

To put this into an answer, instead of just comments, I would use this as an opportunity to recreate your current process.

1. I would first export the entire DE onto a local drive.
2. Set a limit on Field Size for each column
3. Set a Field Type for each column
4. I would then break the Fields out via Excel or preferred software into multiple related data tables
5. Ensure there is at least 1 unique key tying each table to others.

This will let you take a field that maybe has the same value repeating multiple times in the single DE, and reduce it to only a couple entries based on a key in another field. For example if Assigned is only 'Yes' or 'No', and is based on if Job equals 'Started' - 'Yes', but if Job equals 'Not Started' or 'Completed' - 'No'.

You can have 2 DEs, one that has the Job values attached to the Unique ID for each Job, and another DE that contains 3 entries (the 3 job values) and the corresponding values for 'Assigned' (Yes/No) - greatly reducing the necessary storage and processing space.

It should also increase your capability to update/add without needing to do bulk uploads adds every time - making it more efficient.